# Bluej ArrayList add

Tags: java, bluej

I'm trying to make a card game, and have my card class and my deck class sort of ready, it compiles ok, but when I try to run deck's method makeDeckFull, i get the output: invalidnumberinvalidnumber...

when I use the showDeck method I then see this instead of "hearts", 1
Cards@597f13c5 (i do not know what it means, or how to fix it)

Any help would be kindly appreciated: code below.

Deck Class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Deck
{
    private ArrayList<Cards> deck;
    private int index;

    public Deck()
    {
        deck = new ArrayList<Cards>();
    }

    public void makeDeckFull()
    {
        Cards h1 = new Cards("Hearts", 1);
        Cards h2 = new Cards("Hearts", 2);
        Cards h3 = new Cards("Hearts", 3);
        deck.add(h1);
        index ++;
        deck.add(h2);
        index ++;
        deck.add(h3);
        index ++;
        //Rest of these is left out to conserve space
    }

    public void showDeck()
    {
        System.out.println(deck); 
    }
```

Card class:

```
public class Cards
{
    private String HEARTS = "Hearts";
    private String CLUBS = "Clubs";
    private String DIAMONDS = "Diamonds";
    private String SPADES = "Spades";
    public int number;
    public String suit;
    public Cards()
    {
        suit = "unknown suit";
        number = 0;
    }

    public Cards(String suit, int number)
    {
        setSuit(suit);
        setNumber(number);

    }

    public void setCard(String suit, int number2)
    {
        setSuit(suit);
        setNumber(number2);

    }
    public void setSuit(String newSuit)
    {
        if(
            (newSuit.equalsIgnoreCase(HEARTS)) ||
            (newSuit.equalsIgnoreCase(DIAMONDS)) ||
            (newSuit.equalsIgnoreCase(CLUBS))    ||
            (newSuit.equalsIgnoreCase(SPADES)))
        {
            suit = newSuit;
        }
        else 
        {
            newSuit = "invalid";
            System.out.print("Invalid");
        }        
    }
    public int getNumber()
    {
        return number;
    }
    public String getSuit()
    {
        return suit;
    }

    public void setNumber(int newNumber)
    {

        if(newNumber >0 && newNumber <=10)
        {
            number = newNumber;
        }
        else
        {
            number = 0;
            System.out.print("invalid number");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see a `setDeck` method. Also, the `Cards@597f13c5` means you haven't overridden the `toString` method in the Cards class.

Comment: Or the `print` method.

Comment: my bad for beeing unclear, i'l edit right away, makeDeckFull method and showDeck, sorry again.

Comment: Any chance you could still reply though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You need to override `toString()` in the `Cards` class. As is, you are printing out the reference of the object(the gibberish) instead of the "data." You should also override the `toString()` method of `Deck` to only print out the list.

2) I'm stepping through your code snippet of `makeDeckFull()`, and it seems to work fine. Are you sure those three inserts are where you are getting the invalid print statements?

Comment: how do i override toString()?

Comment: Wow, that actually worked!, even though i don't know how... ty man!

Comment: I'd vote you it up too if i had enough rep ;)  if ur still on, if i had an arraylist with 52 cards now, and i have a random generator to pick on out at random, can i somehow print out the location of that card in the list?